# Reverse significance formula

Tags: statistics

In order to calculate significance of an experiment, I have the following observed and expected values:

```
observed: 10 conversions, 20 non conversions
expected: 30 * 0.03 conversions, 30 * (1 - 0.03) non conversions
```

In order to calculate Chi I use this formula:

```
Chi2 = (10 - 30 * 0.03)^2 / (30 * 0.03) + (20 - 30 * (1 - 0.03))^2 / (30 * (1 - 0.03))
```

So far so good. Now I want to reverse the formula, so that Chi is given and 0.03 is searched, so I replace it with x:

```
Chi2 = (10 - 30 * x)^2 / (30 * x) + (20 - 30 * (1 - x))^2 / (30 * (1 - x))
```

Or a more general version:

```
Chi2 = (c - t * x)^2 / (t * x) + (n - t * (1 - x))^2 / (t * (1 - x))
```

where `c = conversion, n = non conversion, t = total`.

But right now I am struggling at getting the x out of the formula, to have like x = .....
Can you help me?

Comment: Incidentally, your expression is chi-squared rather than chi

Comment: multiply both sides by $tx(1-x)$ and expand and I suspect the cubic term $x^3$ will disappear so you will get a quadratic equation in $x$ which you can then solve easily so long as you are careful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Henry's tip I found the solution:

```
x1/2 = (c^2 + 2 * t * c - n^2 + 2 * t * n - t^2 + y * t +- sqrt((-c^2 - 2 * t * c + n^2 - 2 * t * n + t^2 - y * t)^2 + 4 * t^2 * c^2 - 8 * t * c^3 - 8 * t * n * c^2 - 4 * y * t * c^2))/(-2 * t^2 + 4 * t * c + 4 * t * n + 2 * y * t)
```

Sry, I don't know how to format that in a better way.